# PowerShell run multi scripts

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a way to create a script that runs multi scripts? Also the first script should finish before next script is allowed to start.

Example:

```
.\script1.ps1 arg1

#wait until script1 is done
.\script2.ps1 arg1 arg2

#wait until script2 is done
.\script3.ps1 arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the example you gave is a valid script, just put it in a script file and run it.

Answer (score 3):

just try :

```
.\script1.ps1 arg1;.\script2.ps1 arg1 arg2;.\script3.ps1 arg1 arg2
```